# Примеры заимствований и историзмов

Tags: лексика

Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры слов трех групп:

1. Исконно рус. слова, не вышедшие из употр.
2. Заимствования - историзмы
3. Исконно русские слова - историзмы

Answer (score -1):

1,3 Русскому языку 300 лет, может переформулировать в:

1. Исконно старославянские/?древнерусские? слова, не вышедшие из употр.
   И
2. Исконно старославянские/?древнерусские? слова - историзмы

Comment: Пруг — историзм? Саранча исчезла?

Comment: @Aer, это архаизм?

Comment: @СтепанПопов да.

Comment: @Aer Да, пожалуй, Вы правы, пока ещё осталась https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANMgTPVw47Q